# Trying to download data from a password protected website

Tags: java, authentication, session-cookies, password-protection

I have a URL with data I would like to access. The data is in text form and it is password protected...but here's the thing...it is password protected by a login on a different website. Every time I try to gain access to the data URL, I get an HTTP 500 error. Any suggestions for this issue? I don't think this is a very common problem considering I have not come across it in my many Stackoverflow and Google searches.

Below is an example of one of the programs I have tried using to no avail...(Some of the information is private, so I changed the username, password, and url)

```
package Apache1;
//import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;

/**
 * A simple example that uses HttpClient to execute an HTTP request against
 * a target site that requires user authentication.
 */
public class Apache2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUsername", "myPASSWORD"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("LOGIN_WEBSITE");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());

                        URL oracle = new URL("DATA_WEBSITE");
                        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    yc.getInputStream()));
                        String inputLine;
                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                            System.out.println(inputLine);
                        in.close(); 
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer due to lack of details. The code you showed - what is the problem with it? What output does it give? Where does it fail? Any errors? Also, it's essential to understand the exact way the site works with the password site. There is usually some sort of token returned and passed between password and target site. Did you check how it works?

Comment: The error I get is an HTTP 500 error. It's basically saying that I am not logged into the data url. Here's what I found out when I tried to learn more about the password protection:  The identity of the website has been verified bt a VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server but does not have public audit records, the connection to the login website is encrypted with modern cryptography, using a TLS 12, and it is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and ECDHE_RSA

Comment: **Where** are you getting the 500 error in the code? Have you verified that your login is successful? And the website's security certificate has nothing to do with any of this. To find out how the password check is done you'll need to read the Javascript in the site and see what it's doing.

Comment: The error is occurring at the line where I try to log into the data website. I can log in fine into the login site, but the issue is that, when I try to access the data website, a session doesn't seem to have been created. I am trying to find out how to create a session for this data url. When I look at the JavaScript, I can tell that the website uses cookies to create session, but I have never coded using cookies, so I think that's where I am stuck.